# Waiting for an event to happen on the server?

Tags: javascript, post, stream, request

Say I'm making a messaging web app (for example). Sending messages is easy enough; I can just use a POST request for that. But what if I want to be notified when a new message arrives? How can I handle that on the client and server?

Should I open an http request on the client to the server, and have the server simply wait until there's a new message before returning? How does Facebook do it?

Answer (score 0):

I remember trying to reverse engineer facebook's approach but that was a few years ago. It seems like they just have one long request that returns only after a certain timeout (in which case, it retries) or if an interesting event has happened (which then triggers a few other queries).

Check out the following links:

http://ajaxpatterns.org/HTTP_Streaming
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#HTTP_server_push

A little googling turns out a nice feature of html5. Haven't tried this before, but it seems to do the same thing:
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/